# how can i relate two-person accounts to each other in financial services cloud?

Tags: financial-services-cloud

to relate a business account and a household we use account account relationship

to relate 2 contacts or clients we use contact contact relationship

to relate 2 person account what we should use ?

Contact-Contact Relationship or
Account Account Relationship?

Answer (score 0):

to relate 2 person account you should use Contact-Contact Relationship

Answer (score 0):

i was thinking the same till i found this explanation

﻿

Explanation:
To configure a custom field for reporting when relating two-person accounts to each other, the Financial Services Cloud consultant should configure the custom field on the Account Account Relationship object. The Account Account Relationship object is a junction object that links two accounts together and defines their relationship type and role. By configuring a custom field on the Account Account Relationship object, the consultant can capture additional information about how two-person accounts are related to each other and use it for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The **Account-Account Relationship** object is specifically designed to capture relationships between two Person Accounts. This object allows you to store information about the nature of the relationship, such as family ties, business partnerships, or shared financial accounts.